# Is a question about how a part of views works appropriate?

Tags: discussion

I'm having a problem with a view throwing an error when I try to do an csv export on it. In my course of troubleshooting, I am re-creating original view as another view, click by click, in hopes of either finding what piece makes it blow up, or else coming out with another view that gives me what I want.

I've set up the relationships in the second view to visually match the relationships in the first view (entities, required relationships, etc.) but still when I look at the SQL, the new view is joining on different tables and fields than the first view is. I don't see where else I can specify to views how to join tables. I was thinking about writing a views alter hook, but then I wnated to double check myself to see if I was doing it the right way.

Since I'm working on proprietary code, I can't point people to the site or share the views code. I was thinking about posting a question on Drupal Answers asking how views decides on which tables and fields to do joins, in code. That way I could perhaps see precisely what is going on, and fix it.

If I ask about my particular problem, I'm expecting that people will answer "Just click  on the relationships section and make sure that's all correct". As far as I can tell, they are visually identical, and I can't show it to people for them to review anyway. So since that question will be fruitless and inapplicable to others, I was thinking a more general question would be useful for myself and other users. I want to double-check my work at a lower level, but I don't know where to begin, and so far all my googling has returned very basic explanations of SQL relationships.

So then, my question would be about the workings of views, irregardless of my particular problem. Is such a question appropriate for Drupal Answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can understand why you asked (based on the advice in the help center), but I honestly don't think there'll be a problem with you posting that question.

It's nice and specific to a single part of the process, you've obviously done you're research, and if you get a good answer it's bound to be useful to others in the future.

One thing I would say is that a brief description of what you already know, and exactly what you're looking to find out (and in what format if possible), would be useful to potential answerers.

Other than that, I say go for it